# API BluePrint documentation tool

Tags: apiblueprint

I am new to this API Blueprint tool. Can anyone explain me how to use this tool for capturing all my Restful web services API using API Blueprint like this (https://clever.com/developers/docs/explorer#endpoint_districts_districts)?
 Any Help

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid we do not really offer a tool to generate an APIBlueprint starting from real API calls.

The main reason behind this choice is, as said, we believe that documentation and API definition is the first step to design great APIs, and not the last one.

I hope this clarifies the point of view.